# using $this with jquery plug in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying this code to reverse the even text in ul text :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.reverseText = function () {
        var x = "";
        var x = this.text();
        var y = "";
        for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            y += x.charAt(i);
        }
        this.text(y);
    };
    $("ul li:even").reverseText();
});
```

and the html code is :

```
<ul>
    <li>this text0</li>
    <li>this text1</li>
    <li>this text2</li>
    <li>this text3</li>
</ul>
```

but the output is showing the text0 and text2 both reversed together
like this :

- 2txet siht0txet siht
- this text1
- 2txet siht0txet siht
- this text3

I have tried to write it like this :

```
$.fn.reverseText = function () {
    this.each(function () {
        var x = "";

        var x = this.text();

        var y = "";
        for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            y += x.charAt(i);
        }

        this.text(y);

    });
};
```

but it gives an error that this.text() is not a function neither the $(this).text() works

how can I fix this ?

Comment: can you make any fiddle?

Comment: In the each context this is not a jquery yet a dom element. Try this.innerHTML or a console.log(this) to check what it actually is.

Comment: `alert`?!?! use `console.log()` instead. (It won't solve your problem but will make life easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scope of `each` function `this` refers to dom object. you need to make it as jquery object

```
$.fn.reverseText = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var x = $(this).text();
        var y = "";
        for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            y += x.charAt(i);
        }
        $(this).text(y);
    });
};
$("ul li:even").reverseText().css("color","red");
```

In a more cleaner way, you can do like this too,

```
$.fn.reverseText = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text().split('').reverse().join(''));
    });
};
$("ul li:even").reverseText().css("color", "red");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/55/)

Comment: Just consider to return matched set to keep chaining: `return this.each(...);`

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in CSS only:

```css
ul li:nth-child(odd) span { /* odd not even because `:nth-child()` is 1 based */
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>this text0</span></li>
    <li><span>this text1</span></li>
    <li><span>this text2</span></li>
    <li><span>this text3</span></li>
</ul>
```